# Changing which Python Coderunner 3.0 uses to Anaconda's python

Tags: python-3.x, coderunner

I use the Coderunner 3.0 application on my mac for all of my python coding. I don't know how to import any libraries to it and when writing sys.executable in Coderunner it prints /usr/bin/python3. I want to use the version of Python I have from anaconda which is in /Users/myuser/anaconda3/bin but when putting that in the run command nothing changed. Does anyone know how to do this?

python3 $filename anaconda/bin is what I tried using

and when I just enter
    Users/myuser/anaconda3/bin in the run command it says Users/myuser/anaconda3/bin is a directory

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As described on the CodeRunner [support page](https://coderunnerapp.com/support), the syntax for the run command is essentially:

`/path/to/interpreter $filename`

So if Anaconda is located at `/Users/myuser/anaconda3/bin`, the correct command would be:

`/Users/myuser/anaconda3/bin/python3 $filename`